# Writing prompt window input in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, prompt

I am trying to make a small program which whenever I write a number in text field the prompt will show that time and each time it shows I can write some thing in it. Now I wonder how to show the data of the prompt windows. This is my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Write the Words</TITLE>
<script>
function array(){
var words = new Array (parseInt(document.getElementById("box").value)) ;
for ( k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k++) {
var a=[window.prompt( "Enter Your Word " + "" )] ;

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="box" name="t1" ><input type="button" id="bt" onclick="array()"    value="input value">
<p id="p"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan, i dont think you want the second `var` :)

Comment: You think correctly :)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
function array(){
  var a=[], words = new Array(parseInt(document.getElementById("box").value,10)) ;
  for (var k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k++) {
    a.push(window.prompt("Enter Your Word"));
  }
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=a.join("<br/>")
}
```

Comment: how i can sort these outcomes of prompt windows??